# Scp command is not working

Tags: ubuntu

I have created a dump file over the server with **mysqldump** 
**mysqldump -uusername  -ppassword db_name table_name > dump_name**.
Then when I am trying to download the file it is saying 
**scp root@ipaddress:~/ filess~/** 
and when i type password  scp: /root: not a regular file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to copy the whole root directory because you have a space there after the / in `scp root@ipaddress:~/ filess~/`

```
scp user@ip:/path/to/source/file /destination/folder/on/local/machine/
```

and if you want to copy a folder you have to use `-r`

Edit: 
This worked -> Make a directory `/tmp/testfolder/` . Copy your file to this folder. Do `scp root@ipaddress:/tmp/testfolder/* /tmp/` .

Comment: scp root@ipaddres:~/ filess~/ /home/techbirds/folder-name/filess when I am doing this getting error scp: /root: not a regular file
cp: cannot stat ‘filess~/’: No such file or directory

Comment: go to you file and type `pwd` .

is your file stored on the root@ipaddres machine?

Comment: yes it is stored there only

Comment: So login on this machine, go to you file and do `pwd` and write it here.

Comment: when I login using ssh root@ip-address and then type ls command my files and all folders are listed over there .I need to copy my file name " filess"

Comment: when I do pwd filess its gives me output /root

Comment: then use `scp root@ipaddress:/root/filess /tmp/` - your file should then be stored in /tmp/ on you local machine. Does you filename "filess" have a space in front of the f?

Comment: what do you mean by Does you filename "filess" have a space in front of the f

Comment: Because you always wirte " filess" and not "filess" - it looks like you pressed the spacebar in front of the word.

Comment: Other option: Make a directory `/tmp/testfolder/` . Copy your file to this folder. Do `scp root@ipaddress:/tmp/testfolder/* /tmp/`